# Clase no muestra valores de tabla

Tags: php

Quisiera saber por qué los valores de la consulta no son mostrados en el arreglo de la clase.

```
    public function login($usuario, $clave){
        try {
                $query = "SELECT usuario, privilegio, estado FROM sc_usuario WHERE usuario = :usuario AND clave = :clave";

                $BD = new conecta();

                $resultado = $BD->prepare($query);
                $resultado->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $resultado->bindParam(':clave', $clave, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $resultado->execute();

                while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $usuario = new UsuarioVO(   $fila['usuario'],
                                                $fila['privilegio'],
                                                $fila['estado']
                                            );
                }

                return $usuario;
```

Esta es la clase Usuario

```
    public function getUsuario(){
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    public function setUsuario($usuario){
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
    }

    public function getClave(){
        return $this->clave;
    }

    public function setClave($clave){
        $this->clave = $clave;
    }
etc....
```

La tabla tiene 5 campos: usuario, clave, privilegio, estado, idpersona
Y en en la función loguin quiero capturar solamente Usuario, Privilegio y Estado.

Y si le hago un **print_r($usuario)** luego del **while{}** me muestra

```
usuarioVO Object ( [usuario:usuarioVO:private] => [clave:usuarioVO:private] => [privilegio:usuarioVO:private] => [estado:usuarioVO:private] => [idpersona:usuarioVO:private] => )
```

Los muestra vacios y me muestra todos los campos.
Cuál es el problema?

Comment: básicamente se muestra vacío porque hace falta el constructor que reciba los tres atributos de su clase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en este caso es que tu clase debería:

- Tener declarados los **miembros** que representan a la entidad `UsuarioVO`. Los cuales suelen ser `private`
- Tener **un método constructor** el cual, según la lógica de tu programa, debería recibir en parámetro el valor de cada miembro de la clase y asignarlo mediante `$this`.

Vamos a aplicar esto. Comentaré en el mismo código algunos aspectos a tener en cuenta.

#### Clase:

```
class UsuarioVO
{
    private $usuario;
    private $privilegio;
    private $estado;
    private $clave;

    /*
     *Cada parémetro lo declaramos como $parametro=NULL
     *para poder crear instancias de la clase sin parámetros
     *o sólo con algunos parámetros determinados
     *Si no lo hacemos así, tendremos un montón de
     *Warning:  Missing argument  
     *por cada parámetro que omitamos al crear instancias de la clase
     */

    public function __construct($usuario=NULL, $privilegio=NULL, $estado=NULL)
    {
     /*
      *Asignamos los valores recibidos a cada miembro de la clase
     */
        $this->usuario=$usuario;
        $this->privilegio=$privilegio;
        $this->estado=$estado;
    }


    public function getUsuario(){
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    public function setUsuario($usuario){
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
    }

    public function getClave(){
        return $this->clave;
    }

    public function setClave($clave){
        $this->clave = $clave;
    }

    public function getUsuario(){
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    public function setUsuario($usuario){
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
    }

    public function getClave(){
        return $this->clave;
    }

    public function setClave($clave){
        $this->clave = $clave;
    }
}
```

#### Función `login`

Me permitiré optimizarla. En PDO no necesitas `bindParam` (ver comentario en el código).

También, si sólo esperas una fila en el resultado, pon `LIMIT 1` al final de la consulta: `SELECT usuario, privilegio, estado FROM sc_usuario WHERE usuario = :usuario AND clave = :clave LIMIT 1`, y en ese caso accede al resultado sin necesidad del `while`, haciendo esto: `$fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. (No he corregido eso en el código porque no sé si esperas uno o más resultados. De todos modos, la instancia de la clase guardará solamente el último resultado encontrado dentro del `while`, por lo que el `while` no tiene sentido usarlo en este caso).

```
public function login($usuario, $clave){
    try {
            /*Convendría usar LIMIT 1*/
            $query = "SELECT usuario, privilegio, estado FROM sc_usuario WHERE usuario = :usuario AND clave = :clave"; 

            $BD = new conecta();

            $resultado = $BD->prepare($query);
            /*Creamos un array con los parámetros*/
            $arrParams=array(":usuario"=>$usuario, ":clave"=>$clave);
            /*Pasamos los parámetros en el execute*/
            $resultado->execute($arrParams);

            while ($fila = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $usuario = new UsuarioVO(   $fila['usuario'],
                                            $fila['privilegio'],
                                            $fila['estado']
                                        );
            }

            return $usuario;
        }
        //... resto del código
```

---

## Otra posible forma de hacerlo

En PDO podemos obtener una instancia de nuestra clase mapeada del conjunto de resultados. De ese modo, trabajamos con ese objeto usando sus propios métodos. Esa es la finalidad de `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`:

> `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`: devuelve una nueva instancia de la clase solicitada, haciendo corresponder las columnas del conjunto de resultados con los nombres de las propiedades de la clase, y llamando al constructor después, a menos que también se proporcione `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`. Si `fetch_style` incluye `PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE` (por ejemplo, `PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE`), entonces el nombre de la clase se determina a partir del valor de la primera columna.
>
> <sup>[`PDO::FETCH_CLASS` en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)</sup>

Ya que planteaste la duda en un comentario, cuando usamos [`setFetchMode`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php) no invocamos a todos los campos de la clase, sino que le indicamos a PDO *cuál debe ser el modo de obtención para esta sentencia*.

No obstante, cuando haces `$usuario = $stmt->fetch()`, tendrás en `$usuario` un objeto completo, pero esto es lo mismo que si haces `new UsuarioVO`, o sea, se crea una instancia completa de la clase.

En las pruebas que he hecho, si los miembros de la clase tienen el mismo nombre que las columnas de la tabla, PDO asigna de forma inteligente el miembro. O sea, que en un `SELECT` donde tú uses solamente una columna o ciertas columnas, PDO asigna el valor obtenido a cada columna, pienso que basándose en el nombre (sería algo interesante a explorar más adelante). A las columnas que no se incluyen en el `SELECT` PDO les asigna el valor `NULL`.

Aclarado esto, si te interesa esta forma, podrías proceder más o menos así:

### Clase:

La `Clase` podría quedar así. Verás que no ponemos nada en el constructor. PDO asignará a cada miembro su valor correspondiente.

```
class UsuarioVO
{
    private $usuario;
    private $privilegio;
    private $estado;
    private $clave;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }   

    public function getUsuario(){
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    public function setUsuario($usuario){
        $this->usuario = $usuario;
    }

    public function getClave(){
        return $this->clave;
    }

    public function setClave($clave){
        $this->clave = $clave;
    }
}
```

### Consulta:

Primeramente, tendrías que incluir tu clase con `include` o `require`.

Luego, en el código:

```
public function login($usuario, $clave){
    try {
            $query = "SELECT usuario, privilegio, estado FROM sc_usuario WHERE usuario = :usuario AND clave = :clave LIMIT 1";

            $BD = new conecta();

            $stmt = $BD->prepare($query);
            /*Creamos un array con los parámetros*/
            $arrParams=array(":usuario"=>$usuario, ":clave"=>$clave);
            /*Pasamos los parámetros en el execute*/
            $stmt->execute($arrParams);

            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'UsuarioVO' );
            $stmt->execute();
            $usuario = $stmt->fetch();
            return $usuario;
        }
        //... resto del código
```

Observarás que he agregado `LIMIT 1` a la consulta. Supongo que esperas una sola fila en la consulta. El `while` tampoco es necesario. Aquí en caso de haber varios resultados, sólo quedará una instancia de la clase con el último valor. Si necesitas una instancia por cada valor, entonces sí tendría sentido el `while`, pero deberías crear un array de objetos `UsuarioVO`...

Lo que ha ocurrido más arriba ha sido:

- con `setFetchMode` decimos a PDO que queremos una instancia de la clase `UsuarioVO` en los resultados.
- una vez ejecutada la consulta, asignamos en una variable el nuevo objeto: `$usuario = $stmt->fetch();`
- devolvemos ese objeto. Podrás acceder a cada valor llamando a los métodos de la clase. Por ejemplo, para el `usuario`, harías: `echo $persona->getUsuario();`

Si haces un `var_dump($usuario)`, verás algo parecido a este resultado (se trata de una prueba de concepto que hice, aplicando el código explicado más arriba). Verás que hay un objeto `Persona` en este caso y cada columna del `SELECT` se ha asignado a los diferentes miembros de la clase.:

```
object(Persona)#4 (3) {
  ["persona_id":"Persona":private]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["persona_nom":"Persona":private]=>
  string(8) "Santiago"
  ["ciudad_id"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Se trata de una utilidad poco conocida de PDO y que puede ser muy interesante cuando trabajamos con `Clases`.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Tengo algunas dudas: 1) Por qué dices que bindparam no es necesario?, 2) Al asignar en el setFetchMode a 'usuarioVO', no estás invocando a todos los campos de la clase usuario?, suponiendo que la tabla tenga muchos campos, yo solo quiero que el select del DAO me devuelva tres campos, nada más.

Comment: @Piropeator `bindParam` no es necesario porque puedes pasar los parámetros en el `execute` si revisas el código de mi respuesta podrás ver que he comentado algo sobre eso. En cuanto a la forma 2, si en el SELECT hay solo dos columnas PDO asignará esas dos columnas al objeto de la clase. Convendría que los miembros de la clase tengan el mismo nombre de cada columna de la BD. No lo he probado pero creo que eso es suficiente para que asigne a cada miembro el valor de la columna correspondiente. De todos modos si la Forma 2 no te conviene, en la forma 1 también funcionará...

Comment: @Piropeator he editado la respuesta aclarando un poco más tus dudas.

Comment: No sabía lo de pasar parámetros por array. Tuve que cambiar la variable __$stmt__ por __$resultado__ y le di un __print_r($usuario)__ y muestra __usuarioVO Object ( [usuario:usuarioVO:private] => ADMIN [clave:usuarioVO:private] => [privilegio:usuarioVO:private] => 1 [estado:usuarioVO:private] => 1 [idpersona:usuarioVO:private] => )__ es decir, igual va a trabajar con toda la estructura del DAO pero solo los campos del select tendrán valor y los otros NULL, eso no satura la comunicación? pues la estructura igual viaja de cliente al servidor.

Comment: @Piropeator no, eso no satura nada. Cuando tú creas una nueva instancia de la clase con `new` ocurre lo mismo, se crea una instancia de la clase entera, aunque solo asignes valores a algunos miembros, aquellos que no reciban valores  se crearán con valor `NULL` a lo sumo o con el valor por defecto según el contrato de la Clase.

Comment: @ACedano gracias, seguiré mejorando el login de esta aplicación.

Comment: Cuando voy a validar con **if(isset($user){hacer A}else{hacer B}** siempre hace A. Por qué?

Comment: Si `$user` está creado antes, supongo que hará A, y si no, hará B. ¿Qué es lo que quieres evaluar en sí @Piropeator? Si es una clase es mejor usar `if ($user instanceof User){...` pues así verificará es un objeto de ese tipo, no de otro tipo cualquiera.

Comment: La clase login devuelve un objeto, cierto? si el $usuario y la $clave existen y son válidos debería hacer A y si no debería hacer B.